# Authenticate with Identity Server 3 as an Azure AD registered application

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver3

I'm using Identity Server 3 with Azure AD middleware; it works well and I'm able to authenticate as a user via Azure AD. However, I'm trying to extend the implementation such that I can authenticate in a similar manner but as an Azure AD registered application rather than a user. The use case will involve a background application running and authenticating without user input. Has anyone managed to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 0):

What is your scenario? If you want to calls a web API using background application's identity (instead of a user's identity) to get access tokens , you can use [OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) .

Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) for more details about Daemon or Server Application to Web API scenario . Also click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#server-or-daemon-application-to-web-api) for code samples that calls a web API using client credential flow .